# OrhographicCamera fails to render the whole scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently trying to render a scene using three.js and WebGL in an isomorphic  way. I came across some articles that mention the `OrthographicCamera` to achieve this. I added it and noticed some weird results. Part of the scene is now completely black and seems as if it is not being painted.

See this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/vefohapido/3/edit?js,output

When I change the camera to the perspective one, then the whole ground will be visible.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the camera is too close to the origo (the center point of the scene) , some line parts  are over the frustum near plane. Try this:

```
camera.position.x = 300;
camera.position.y = 400;
camera.position.z = 300;
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it. I should read up on the camera and frustum.